# Google Chrome CSS class pseudo-class group not working

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, pseudo-class

I'm not sure if this is really a bug with Google Chrome, but here is what happens:

When I nest the pseudo-class `a:link`, `a:visited` in a class, all `<a>` elements in the page will get the latest color set in the nesting. It only happens with the color property. In other browser it does not happen, I'm using Google Chrome 30.0.1599.69 m

CSS:

```
.cat ul{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin-top:10px;
    padding-left:10px;
}

.cat a:link, a:visited {
    margin-top: 3px;
    font:15px arial,sans-serif;
    display:block;
    color:#000000;
    text-align:left;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.cat a:hover,a:active {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}



.menu ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.menu li {
    float:left;
}

.menu a:link,a:visited {
height:35px;
padding-top:8px;
    display:block;
    width:120px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:#2d0000;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}

.menu a:hover,a:active {
    background-color:#7A991A;
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>TITLE</title>
</head>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="site">

            <div id="header">
                <div id="logo"><img src="./img/logo.png" /></div>
                <div id="cart"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="subheader">
                <div id="menu" class="menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div id="searchbar">
                    <form>
                        <input type="text" name="search" /> <input type="submit" name="ok" value="Search" />
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div id="body">
            <div id="category" class="cat">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="main">
                <a>Test</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the expected result? I'm not seeing what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you set `.cat a:link` and all `a:visited` to black color - all a in `.cat` and all a in hole css `a:visited` are set to black..

```
.cat a:link, a:visited {
    .....
}
```

Here you set `.menu a:link` and `a:visited` to white. So all `a:visited` will be white... Not only in .menu...

```
.menu a:link,a:visited {
.....
}
```

I think you have mistake in `.cat a:link, a:visited` - it should be `.cat a:link, .cat a:visited`. Same mistake in `.menu a:link, a:visited` - this should be `.menu a:link, .menu a:visited`